# CakePHP 3: order of translated data with missing translation strings

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I use TranslationBehavior to handle translated data in my app. When retrieving data, CakePHP returns the translated string or if this string is not available, the value of the default locale. To request the data, the following query is used:

```
$items = $this->Model->find('all')
  ->all()
  ->extract('name');
```

To order the output, the query is:

```
$items = $this->Model->find('all')
  ->order([$this->Model->translationField('name') => 'ASC'])
  ->all()
  ->extract('name');
```

This works for all default locale items and all translated items. But when the translation for a record is missing, it will break the order. In this case the correct fallback value is returned, but the order is no longer correct. The output looks like this:

```
['A... (Translated)', 'B... (Translated)', 'A... (Default)', 'C... (Default)']
```

What I expect is the following order:

```
['A... (Default)', 'A... (Translated)', 'B... (Translated)', 'C... (Default)']
```

To achieve this, I changed the query to:

```
$items = $this->Model->find('all')
  ->order(['IF('.$this->Model->translationField('name').' != "", '.$this->Model->translationField('name').', Model.name)' => 'ASC'])
  ->all()
  ->extract('name');
```

Which gives the expected order:

```
['A... (Default)', 'A... (Translated)', 'B... (Translated)', 'C... (Default)']
```

**The question is:** is this the correct way to handle the order of mixed locales? Or did I miss something and CakePHP already provides a simpler solution?

You may ask, why should we mix the locales? In my case, it's not necessary to translate all the strings, because some of the items are identical in both languages.

Comment: I can't test this right now... but I'd say you probably generally shouldn't store empty strings, ie if there is no translation, then don't store a translation record.

Comment: Yes you are right, empty strings should not be stored. But even if the translation record is missing, the order will only be correct for the default locale OR the translation locale when using `$this->Model->translationField('name')`. But not for a mix of both.

Comment: I see... I'll have a look at it later on in case nobody else chimps in. This could very well be the correct/expected behavior.

Comment: Totally forgot about this... sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at how CakePHP queries the translated fields, and merges them later on at PHP level, this is the expected behavior, and you'd indeed have to use a conditional expression in the `ORDER` clause.

I'd suggest to use a `CASE` expression, as the `IF()` function is MySQL specific, something like:

```
$query = $this->Model->find();
$query
    ->orderAsc(
        $query->newExpr()->addCase(
            [
                $query->newExpr()->isNotNull($this->Model->translationField('name'))
            ],
            [
                $query->identifier($this->Model->translationField('name')),
                $query->identifier('Model.name')
            ]
        )
    )
    // ...
```

Which would generate an expression similar to:

```sql
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN Model_name_translation.content IS NOT NULL
        THEN Model_name_translation.content
        ELSE Model.name END
    ASC
```

And as mentioned in the comments, If you go the "*do not translate identical strings*" route, then you should avoid storing empty strings for such "missing" translations, instead do not store a record for them at all.

In order to avoid all this you could of course add translations for everything, even if they are equal in the different languages.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I also searched for alternative solutions, but I always ended up with such additional order parameters similar to the one I already described in my question. Your solution perfected this idea. Thanks for this! And regarding empty translations: sure, not storing a record should be preferred for missing translations.